# Error running app on devise dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have Xcode 10.3 and iPhone 11. When I run the project there are no errors. It compiles, and then throws an error

> dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed

In the Devices and Simulators window, my iPhone 11 defines it as iPhone 4. I think the problem is somewhat related to this. Because iPhoneX on the same system (13.3.1) starts up normally.

I watched a lot of sites where they say add files, etc., but that doesn’t help me.
I will be grateful for the help

Comment: Maybe this can help you : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3jST08imY0 <br>
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108917

Comment: I tried this too, the result is the same